# reproduce select distinct with get_db_data

Tags: wikimedia

I am using for the first time MediaWiki so I apologize if this is a trivial question.
I am retrieving data from an external database using

```
{{#get_db_data:
db=mydb
|from=tabledata
|data=ts=ts,obs=observer,des=description
}}
```

How can I obtain with this parser the same effect of the sql command `SELECT DISTINCT` ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that this is possible by adding `DISTINCT` as follows

```
{{#get_db_data:
db=mydb
|from=tabledata
|data= des = DISTINCT description
}}
```